# Jumps of jump diffusions

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $W$ be a Brownian motion and $N$ a Poisson random measure defined on $\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R_0^n$ ($\mathbb R_0^n:=\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$) with compensator $\tilde N(dt,dz):= N(dt,dz) - dt \,\nu(dz)$, in which $\nu$ is a Levy measure so that $\int_{\mathbb R_0^n} 1 \wedge |z|^2 \nu(dz) < \infty$. For some $c \in (0, \infty]$, consider the SDE $$dX(t) = b(X(t-))dt + \sigma(X(t-))dW(t) + \int_{|z| < c} \gamma(X(t-),z)\tilde N(dt,dz).$$ Suppose that the functions $b,\sigma,$ and $\gamma$ are nice so that a strong solution exists and is pathwise unique. For instance, under the usual linear growth and Lipschitz condition, the SDE has a unique strong solution; see, for example, Applebaum 2009, Levy Processes and Stochastic Calculus, Second Edition, Theorem 6.2.3.

My question is: Is it possible to characterize the jumps $\Delta X(t):= X(t) - X(t-)$ using the coefficients of the SDE? Or to estimate moments like $\mathbb E[|\Delta X(t)|^p]$, $p=1,2,$ etc? Many thanks!